# How to import products from Woocommerce to Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, woocommerce

I want to import products from Woocommerce to Magento in my local setup.Is there any extension or Tutorial available?..Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

please use this extension for  import products from Woocommerce to Magento
https://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/shopping-cart-migration-options/6684-woocommerce-to-magento-migration

Comment: I need to work in my local setup....this link needs live link...@
Faraz Bashir

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you upload your both sites to an online server then perform the migration?

For more convenience, you could also use this [Magento migration service](https://next-cart.com/supported-carts/magento/), they can help you upload your sites to their server then perform the migration. Chat with them first to make sure they will do it.